# An application comes with a .desktop file; how do I use it?

Tags: debian, cinnamon, devuan, mate-panel

I'm using the mate-panel on Devuan 2.0 ASCII (~= Debian 9.0 Stretch).

I've downloaded this (binary) application which I've placed in `/opt/the_app`. I have a link to its binary under `/usr/local/bin/the_app`. Now, the app's distribution comes with a `.desktop` file and an `.ico` file it links to. How do I use this file to see Zotero in my desktop environment's launcher? Or - should I not use it directly at all?

The file's contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TheApp
Exec=bash -c "$(dirname $(readlink -f %k))/the_app_binary -url %U"
Icon=the_app.ico
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Office;
MimeType=text/plain
```

Comment: Off-topic: get a look at antix Linux and their FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the `.desktop` file in `/usr/local/share/applications` and it should show up in your launcher automatically. This is described in [the Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html) (which specifies `.desktop` files).

The icon should go in `/usr/local/share/icons`; see [the Icon Theme Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html).

Comment: Do I need to do something about the relative reference to the ico file (see edited version)? Anyway, +1.